# CGCaptureAllDisplaysWithOptions(kCGCaptureNoFill) still fills the screens with black

Tags: osx-mavericks, quartz-graphics

I'm programming a cocoa app which uses scripting bridge to interact with menus in a specific frontmost application, but I don't want the user to see all the gibberish that scripting bridge is doing.

So I want to freeze the image of all monitors during that phase and I'm trying to use

```
CGCaptureAllDisplaysWithOptions(kCGCaptureNoFill);
```

which supposedly do that until i call the

```
CGReleaseAllDisplays();
```

But it won't, all the screens turn black.

I have tried the solution here "[CGDisplayCaptureWithOptions (kCGDirectMainDisplay, kCGCaptureNoFill) still fills the screen with black](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434511/cgdisplaycapturewithoptions-kcgdirectmaindisplay-kcgcapturenofill-still-fills)" to capture the screen one by one but stills they turn black.

**Someone know why? Is there some workaround?**

I also tried a more complex approach, taking screenshots of every screen before capture, using `CGDisplayCreateImage`. But another problem arouse when i try to draw them directly to the screen context. I got the context using `CGDisplayGetDrawingContext` and call the `CGContextDrawImage` to draw the images for each one of the screens. 
With only one or mirrored screens works fine but with extended screens only works on my main screen, the other show a sub image of the screenshot.

For example:

- Main Screen:

  ```
  CGDisplayBounds returns {{0, 0}, {1280, 800}} 

  CGRect rect1 = {{0, 0}, {CGImageGetWidth(screenshot1), CGImageGetHeight(screenshot1)}}; 

  CGContextDrawImage(context1, rect1, screenshot1); //<- works fine
  ```
- Other Screen

  ```
  CGDisplayBounds returns {{1280, 0}, {1920, 1080}} 

  CGRect rect2 = {{0, 0}, {CGImageGetWidth(screenshot2), CGImageGetHeight(screenshot2)}};

  CGContextDrawImage(context2, rect2, screenshot2); //<-Shows a sub image of my screenshot with origin at (1280, 0) and frame {{1280, 0}, {1280 - 1920, 1080}}
  ```

Sub image that appears on the monitor:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoUWe.jpg

Original Screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHjN6.jpg

**Any suggestions?**